# How to change the position of column in reverse manner in PySpark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have PySpark dataframe in which I need to reverse the position of columns.

Example:

```
df:
+--------------------+-------+
|          indication|row_num|
+--------------------+-------+
|Psoriasis, modera...|      1|
|Diabetes mellitus...|      2|
|Diabetes mellitus...|      3|
|Diabetes mellitus...|      4|
|systemic lupus er...|      5|
|Diabetes mellitus...|      6|
|Diabetes mellitus...|      7|
+--------------------+-------+
```

Desirable output:

```
df_output:
+---------+---------------------+
|row_num  |  indication         |
+---------+---------------------+
|  1      | Psoriasis, modera...|      
|  2      | Diabetes mellitus...|      
|  3      | Diabetes mellitus...|      
|  4      | Diabetes mellitus...|      
|  5      | systemic lupus er...|      
|  6      | Diabetes mellitus...|      
|  7      | Diabetes mellitus...|      
+---------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the reversed columns list:

`df_output = df.select(df.columns[::-1])`